# 2 buttons, 1 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a simple form that looks like so

```
<% remote_form_for post, :url => post_path(post), :method => :put do |f| -%>
  <%= f.submit "Approve" %>
  <%= f.submit "Deny" %>
<% end -%>
```

Which renders

```
<input type="submit" value="Approve" name="commit"/>
<input type="submit" value="Deny" name="commit"/>
```

In my controller I have the following logic

```
@post.approved =  params[:commit] == 'Approve' ? true : false
```

So problem is that if the user clicks the "Approve" button or the "Deny" button the parameter that is sent is that `:commit => "Approve"`.

Does anybody know of a bug relating to this or another (simple) way to perform the same functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: For some reason I fear any title that follows the form "2 X, 1 Y"

Comment: Sorry, it may be considered bad "form" but I wanted something that would catch your eye ;)

Comment: @vrish88, I don't think its about bad form, but its about which association you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS lib (Prototype I guess) doesn't know what button was pressed. It just serializes the form field values for the Ajax request. When using normal form POST, browsers attach right value to the commit param.

You can add hidden form field (eg action). Then add JS code to set required value of the hidden field when appropriate button is pressed (and before the Ajax request is sent).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to override the "name" parameter of the second button.

```
<%= f.submit "Deny", :name => "commit_deny" %>
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work. When Prototype serializes the form it takes the first submit button it sees.

Comment: actually it takes both params and then rails only keeps the first. https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/672-formserialize-and-multiple-submit-buttons

Answer (score 0):

I think Submit is unique per form (HTML thing) so yopu have two options:

1. Use 2 forms whith 1 submit each, that lead to the same action (CSS it to you liking)
2. Use 2 button-type controls (i.e. not submits) and submit with both onClick events (javascript needed)